# When clicking on JQuery search filter box, header disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cross-browser, cordova

note: this works perfectly fine on firefox, chrome, the only issue is using mobile browser (iphone/android)

I created a webpage that mimics an address book(phone book) using jQuery/jQuery mobile, and i have all the contacts in a list, and have a search filter bar to search through the contacts.

```
<ul id="Addressbook" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Type name here for filter search" data-filter-theme="f" data-inset="true">
```

additionally, on loading the page i already declared

```
$("[data-role=footer]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });
$("[data-role=header]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });
```

except, with i click on the search filter bar, the CSS will be messed up (the search filter bar will move to around 70% of the height of the screen and all other css that is linked with positioning (z-index) will be skewed (absolute/fixed positioning wont work either).
But, after completely typing the filter and pressing "done" on phone, the CSS refreshes to the original state, i was wondering if it were possible to prevent the default behavior, ive tried using preventdefault, but it didnt help.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can investigate exactly what happens in the jquery source code for fixed headers, specifically for you line 10116 of jquery mobile source code (not minified one).
First that listview will have input element on top of it, so if that problem happens when you click on it, it means something is wrong with fixed headers and focusin event, so lets find where fixed header is defined, then go down till we reach what we need.

Fixed headers will still be hidden if the screen is less then certain size, for example this line

```
.bind( "focusin focusout", function( e ) {
      if ( screen.width < 1025 && $( e.target ).is( o.hideDuringFocus ) && !$( e.target ).closest( ".ui-header-fixed, .ui-footer-fixed" ).length ) {}
```

will trigger that hide on fixed header, so you can disable it by going to this line and just after the brackets before that if statement add

```
.bind( "focusin focusout", function( e ) {
    return false;
    //you can keep rest of the code
```

That will keep headers on, and hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks :) it keeps the header on now, but the CSS is still skewed (namely) z-index, is there any way around it?

Comment: never mind, its still an open issue with JQuery Mobile that is unresolved, your solution does fix the header, but the shifting of the CSS is still unresolved as of a month ago.

Comment: can you give the link to the issue, I presume it is on jquery mobile github? I want to see :)